# How to GET multiple commits with REST Api from an on-premises TFS server 2018?

Tags: git, rest, powershell, azure-devops

Consider the [GetCommits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API. It has an optional parameter `searchCriteria.ids` which is a list of commit Ids.

But how to pass this list? For example, I have 2 commits A and B. I tried:

1. A,B
2. A B
3. [A,B]

The response I get is:

```
An object ID must be 40 characters long and only have hex digits. Passed in object ID: 0533232917cc37fb743d282c467eb41bafac15ee,063a6805640221285db15f75c3b3ca6f3fe619c
```

I get the same response for all the three variants - only the reported object Id differs.

So, how do I pass an array to the Azure Devops REST Api in a GET request?

I use powershell. The statement is simply `Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $Url`

**Variant 1 - use comma**

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/commits?api-version=4.1&searchCriteria.ids=0533232917cc37fb743d282c467eb41bafac15ee,063a6805640221285db15f75c3b3ca6f3fe619c0
```

Results in

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"An object ID must be 40 characters long and only have hex digits. Passed in object ID: 0533232917cc37fb743d282c467eb41bafac15ee,063a6805640221285db15f75c3b3ca6f3fe619c0.","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

**Variant 2 - use space**

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/commits?api-version=4.1&searchCriteria.ids=0533232917cc37fb743d282c467eb41bafac15ee%20063a6805640221285db15f75c3b3ca6f3fe619c0
```

Results in the same error.

**Variant 3 - use JavaScript array [,]**

```
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/code/_apis/git/repositories/xyz/commits?api-version=4.1&searchCriteria.ids=[0533232917cc37fb743d282c467eb41bafac15ee,063a6805640221285db15f75c3b3ca6f3fe619c0]
```

Same error.

It does work when I just pass one commit without any extra symbols.

[image]

**Using *in* instead of *=***

There is a suggestion to use ' in ' instead of '='. This does accept comma, but does not seem to work correctly. Please, observe:

[image]

So, using '=' yields one commit - as expected. But using ' in ' yields 100? I tried passing two commits separated with a comma and it does not fail, but returns 100 commits as well. This is wrong.

Comment: Can you share your whole http message?

Comment: the documentation doesn't specify whether the array needs to be a string array. So it's unclear. here's a simple example of how you could do it: `string[] ids = {"0533232917cc37fb743d282c467eb41bafac15ee", "063a6805640221285db15f75c3b3ca6f3fe619c"};` and then you could pass in the ids array you just created.

Comment: I added an important piece of information - I use powershell. Could you translate it to powershell? Because I already tried what looks like a powershell array, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, comma  way is working for the rest API. The following is demo and test result with Powershell code.You could refer to it. I test it with Azure Devops API.

If there is a space between the ids, I also can reproduce the issue that you mentioned.

```
$pat = "PATToken"
$organization = "organization name"
$project = "project Id"
$repositoryId = "repository Id"
$ids = "266295d9adbxxx,f345970123bxxxx" # Ids of commits
$apiUrl= "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/commits?searchCriteria.ids=$ids&api-version=5.0-preview.1"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET 

foreach($item in $Result.value)
{
  Write-Host "$item"
  Write-Host "---------------"
}
```

**Note:** I also try to test it with API version 4.1, it is also working on my side.

**Test Result:**

[image]

**Update**:

If I use the TFS API I also can reproduce the issue that you mentioned with the code I mentioned.

I can get the result with following way. Please have a try to use **in** to instead of **"="**

The following is my test code:

```
$ids = '0cc4e954c082372379xxxx','9b5983436c2f81b5fae6a72xxx'

$apiUrl= "http://$tfsserver:8080/tfs/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/commits?searchCriteria.ids in $ids&api-version=4.1"
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: I do not know what to say. We have an on-premises VSTS.

Comment: @mark. Please use in to instead of  '=' in the url. I also update my answer, you could refer to it. `$ids = '0cc4e954c082372379xxxx','9b5983436c2f81b5fae6a72xxx'

$apiUrl= "http://$tfsserver:8080/tfs/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryId/commits?searchCriteria.ids in $ids&api-version=4.1"`

Comment: @mark. Thanks for your update.  It is my fault, as you mentioned **in** is not working,  since I test it with only 2 commits. I recommend it you could report it to [TFS teams](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html)